# MVC 5 HttpErrors + Controller/Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http-status-code-404, asp.net-mvc-5

How can I change error path to my controller/action **with httpErrors**?

I have this code:

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
  <remove statusCode="404"/>
  <error responseMode="ExecuteURL" statusCode="404" path="Error/HttpRequestError"/>
</httpErrors>
```

But it doesn't work. Empty page shows and action not entered.

What i do wrong?

P.S. I know about another way to sovle custom page errors. But i want try to use it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I resolve a problem. This code of web.config works:

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
  <remove statusCode="404"/>
  <error statusCode="404" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Error/404"/>
</httpErrors>
```

Now entered in ErrorsController/NotFound action(marked with routing atribute [ActionName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionnameattribute%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) to 404).

Comment: Note that "ExecuteURL" is case sensitive!

Comment: This approach doesn't work for me.  I get the ASP.net "The resource cannot be found." error page.  I am able to access the /Error/404 page directly.  I've tried in IIS Express and IIS.  Any tips?

Comment: @Sean This one is correct but an important notice is that it won't work if you have a virtual directory path or you must also fill it too. I did not know that so it took many hours to find why I could not get it too work.

Comment: Doesn't work on MVC5. Returns a blank page and never hits the controller action.

Comment: I am sorry I am quite new to MVC can you please also show the code of your ErrorController. It be help a lot to aviod confusions. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you simply redirect the url for 404

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly"  defaultRedirect="~/error">
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Error/HttpRequestError" />    
</customErrors
```

Comment: Additional redirect is bad for CEO.

Comment: @SergeyShoshin what is CEO? are you referring SEO?

Comment: Oh, sorry. Exactly SEO.

Comment: @SergeyShoshin CEO doesn't like unnecessary redirects either.

Comment: Whilst having error page issues myself, these comments certainly put a smile on my face :D

Answer (score 1):

If Sergey Shoshin's answer does not work.

```html
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
      <remove statusCode="404"/>
      <error statusCode="404" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="[optional virtual directories...]/Error/404"/>
</httpErrors>
```