# IIS Displaying 404 page even customErrors set to on

Tags: iis, web-config

I added these codes inside my system.web tag in web config

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="Error/Index">
  <error statusCode="404"
       redirect="Error/Index/404" />
  <error statusCode="403"
   redirect="Error/Index/403" />
</customErrors>
```

Redirect is working when i type `localhost/controllername/actioname`

but when i type `localhost/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a`

> it displays an IIS 404 not found page.

Is there any other settings for this? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
  <remove statusCode="404"/>
  <error statusCode="404" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Error/404"/>
</httpErrors>
```

http://benfoster.io/blog/aspnet-mvc-custom-error-pages

[MVC 5 HttpErrors + Controller/Action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20121176/mvc-5-httperrors-controller-action)